# Running htop when system boots (CLI)

Tags: boot, command-line, startup, htop

I have been searching for what feels like ages now, but have not been able to solve this problem. The furthest I have gotten is opening htop on boot, but without any updates(just the initial CPU usage and tasks). This was achieved through running the command called by RC.local.

Any help is more than much appreciated since I am completely lost. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Also, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1342560/edit) your question and add details of what you have tried already so that we are not guessing or giving you information that you have already tried.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using htop you can use a program called **Conky** to display the system information on startup. It is even customizable and have different themes.

Comment: Could you please include the steps on how to use it too?